# Nginx configuration with different ports

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I'm trying to configure the Nginx reverse proxy for a client to a server.
The server is listening on port 80 and 55555 for a client.
I was only be able to pass to a port 80, how is it possible to redirect to 2 different ports?
Thanks in advance.

```
             server {
listen 80;
server_name 192.168.72.100;
return 301 https://192.168.72.100; }
server {
 listen 443 ;
 server_name 192.168.72.100;
 # SSL config
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
        ssl_protocols         SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers           HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_session_cache     shared:SSL:20m;
        ssl_session_timeout   4h;
    access_log /temp/nginx/log/access.log;
    error_log /temp/nginx/log/error.log error;
 set $upstream 192.168.72.135;

 location / {

 proxy_pass_header Authorization;
 proxy_pass http://$upstream;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Connection "";
 proxy_buffering off;
 client_max_body_size 0;
 proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
 proxy_redirect off;
 proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass shows an example of how to specify a port for the upstream:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/uri/;
```

So if you want to forward the request to 192.168.72.135 port 55555, use:

```
proxy_pass http://192.168.72.135:5555;
```

Comment: If this is not the answer you're looking for, please add more detail to your question, it's not very clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer please see this question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54765416/nginx-reverse-proxy-with-web-socket?noredirect=1#comment96311014_54765416